# jQueryUI Themed Controls - Change font size

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, widget

My site is built with all Widgets from jQueryUI.

I wish to offer the user an option to increase the font size of the style class "ui-widget-content", how can an increased font size be applied in the Document.Ready standard event?

ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give some button click or so and in that button click you can do this right

`$('.classname').css("font-size",give your value here);`  // give right selector

see this link which has what you want

http://www.webupd8.org/2009/05/jquery-how-to-add-resize-text-font-size.html